# Does this statement build a new object without the "new" keyword?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am reviewing some MVC ASP.NET tutorial code written in C# with the Entity Framework.

The following method is declared as follows:

```
    public Product GetProduct(int id)
    {
        Product item = repository.Get(id);
        //method statements
    }
```

Some context:
"Product" is also a POCO class containing simple `{get;set;}` properties.
The code above is written in a controller file called `ProductsController.cs`

My question revolves around `Product item = repository.Get(id)`

If Product is a class, then don't you have to instantiate "item" with the "new" keyword?
I'm really not sure how to interpret the statement.  Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: @cHao, that comment should be an answer :)  'cos you're dead right.

Comment: @Moo-Juice: Eh.  I do more comments than answers lately, for some reason.  :)  Answer'd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`repository.Get` already used `new` (or called some function that used `new`) in order to create the object it's returning to you. You don't have to do it (and can't, in fact, since `repository.Get` isn't a type).

Answer (score 0):

`repository.Get(id)` ***returns*** an object of type `Product` which is being assigned to ***object reference*** `item`.